# Why do I get the error: "Editor does not contain a main type" with the following code in Eclipse Photon?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-photon

Right now, I'm trying to teach my friends how to code. I've gotten past some pretty basic stuff and am trying to have them run their code.

I just downloaded the latest **Eclipse** version: **Eclipse Photon**, and have the latest **JDK**. For some reason, the following code throws the error: `"Editor does not contain a main type."` It worked fine when I was using **Oxygen**, so I don't know what would be different.

```
public class Tutorial {

    public static void callMe() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        callMe();
    }
}
```

At this point, I'm trying to teach my friends methods and calling them. I'm about to get to Integers, but for some reason, Eclipse doesn't want to run. I don't know if it's **JavaSE-9** - I used **JavaSE-1.8** with Oxygen - or something else, but I'm really confused because, as you can see, I have a main method.

**EDIT:**
It's a problem with JavaSE-9. Just tried 1.8 and it works fine. Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you try with java8, i have the same issue with java 9 in oxygen also

Comment: @Deadpool just tried it, worked fine. Now I just want to know if there's a way to fix this.

Comment: Also, Netbeans has the same issue with JDK9, you need to switch to JDK8 to property work.

Comment: why don't you use java 10 instead of 9, check here about java 9 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase9-3934878.html

Comment: Java 9 is not a long-term support version and has been obsolete with the Java 10 release in March. Therefore, the recommendation is to use either Java 8 or Java 10 (because Java 7 and Java 9 do not get security updates). In September Java 11 will be released, which is a long-term support version like Java 8.

Comment: What "basic stuff" did you go past? Is the file in a Java Project's Source Folder?

Comment: In case there is a bug in Eclipse it should be fixed, but I cannot reproduce the problem (I've tried using Eclipse Photon in a fresh workspace). Can try to specify the exact steps you did? E.g. How do you try to launch the program?

Comment: @TillBrychcy make a new project in JavaSE-9 and run using f5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine with Java 8. But try these steps once.

1.) Right-click over your class-> Run As ->Run Configurations

2.) Create New Launch Configuration in Java Application.

3.) Give your project and main class in respective options and try to run. Hope it solves but better to use Java 8 as it is stable altogether.